# how do I include all jars related to JRE 1.6 in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I am going to shcedule my java program developed using jdk1.6 on Control-M job scheduler. It means that my job should not fail to start if no supported is JRE is there on which the job is running.

My project leads advised to have the necessary JRE stuff in my project jar(i.e my maven module jar itself).

Please help me how to include JRE1.6 jars in the pom.xml as dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime environment cannot be bundled using pom.xml.

Use a tool such as IZpack and create an installer for your application which contains bundled JRE with it.

http://izpack.org/

Comment: Thanks 18bytes, you mean there is no way in java we can include JRE in the application jar? other than using external tools such as izpack?

Comment: Yes, there is no other way. Additionally you can also check version number of JRE while starting your application.